# Use a specific timeout connected to a retrypolicy

Tags: c#, polly

I'm creating a retry policy the following way:

```
var policy = Policy.Handle<Exception>().WaitAndRetryAsync...
```

How to chail/build a timeout for the retrypolicy above? `Policy.TimeoutAsync` returns a `TimeoutPolicy`, hence I'm not able to do something like

```
var policy = Policy.TimeoutAsync(30).Handle<Exception>().WaitAndRetryAsync...
```

Does the timeout become a common setting for all my retry policies?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

To combine policies, you build each policy separately, then combine them using [PolicyWrap](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/PolicyWrap).

To build an overall timeout which applies across all retries as a whole (ie across the entire operation):

```
var overallTimeoutPolicy = Policy.TimeoutAsync(60); 
var waitAndRetryPolicy = Policy
    .Handle<WhateverException>()
    .WaitAndRetryAsync(/* your wait-and-retry specification*/);
var combinedPolicy = overallTimeoutPolicy.WrapAsync(waitAndRetryPolicy);

await combinedPolicy.ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken => ...)
```

To impose a timeout on each specific try, wrap the retry and timeout policies  in the other order:

```
var timeoutPerTry = Policy.TimeoutAsync(10); 
var waitAndRetryPolicy = Policy
    .Handle<WhateverException>()
    .WaitAndRetryAsync(/* your wait-and-retry specification*/);
var combinedPolicy = waitAndRetryPolicy.WrapAsync(timeoutPerTry);

await combinedPolicy.ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken => ...);
```

Or even use both kinds of timeout (per-try, per-overall-operation):

```
var overallTimeout = Policy.TimeoutAsync(60); 
var timeoutPerTry = Policy.TimeoutAsync(10); 
var waitAndRetryPolicy = Policy
    .Handle<WhateverException>()
    .WaitAndRetryAsync(/* your wait-and-retry specification*/);

var combinedPolicy = Policy
    .WrapAsync(overallTimeout, waitAndRetryPolicy, timeoutPerTry); // demonstrates alternative PolicyWrap syntax

await combinedPolicy.ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken => ...);
```

The [PolicyWrap wiki](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/PolicyWrap) gives full syntax details, and [advice on the effects of different orderings, when combining policies within a wrap](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/PolicyWrap#usage-recommendations).

---

To answer:

> Does the timeout become a common setting for all my retry policies?

Policies apply wherever you use them (whether used individually, or as part of a `PolicyWrap`).

You can [thread-safely](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/master/README.md#thread-safety) use any `TimeoutPolicy` instance you have configured at multiple call sites.  So, to apply that timeout as a common setting for all your retry policies, simply include that same `TimeoutPolicy` instance in the `PolicyWrap` for each call site.  The single `TimeoutPolicy` instance can safely be wrapped with *different* retry policy instances, if desired.

If both your wait-and-retry specification, and timeout specification, are common for all call sites, simply make one `PolicyWrap` instance encompassing both (per above code examples), and re-use that `PolicyWrap` instance everywhere.  Again - thread safe.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer - much appreciated!

Comment: Hi agian, based on your comment, shouldn't this be working? https://pastebin.com/E6RaTWCn A one second timeout policy on a 2 second task. I'm expecting to see "fail: timeoutexception" in the log. Also, I noticed that you advice against `ExecuteAndCapture` with policywraps. What will happen if the last attempt throws an exception if I switch to `Execute`?

Comment: Hi. See Polly's [Timeout doco](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Timeout).  `TimeoutStrategy.Optimistic` (the default) operates by [co-operative cancellation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364.aspx) via `CancellationToken`.  `TimeoutStrategy.Pessimistic` doesn't: it 'walks away' from even an uncancellable execution. `Thread.Sleep(...)` in your pastebin is uncancellable.  Change Sleep() to `Task.Delay(...)` & use `ExecuteAsync()` overload taking a `CancellationToken`, per my examples: `ExecuteAsync(ct => Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), ct), someCancellationToken)`.

Comment: OR, stick with `Thread.Sleep(...)`, and prove to yourself that the `TimeoutPolicy` with`TimeoutStrategy.Pessimistic` successfully times out on this - that is, makes the caller 'walk away' from waiting for the uncancellable `Thread.Sleep(...)`.  Cancellable tasks and `TimeoutStrategy.Optimistic` are preferred and more resource friendly - see wiki.

Comment: Re "What will happen if the last attempt throws an exception if I switch to Execute?" -> The policy will let that exception propagate.  Presumably you want to catch that exception, and your code should decide how to proceed.  The exception being rethrown is there to tell you the operation did not succeed within the configured retry attempts.

Comment: Example showing `TimeoutStrategy.Pessimistic`: https://dotnetfiddle.net/xREDBf . (I reduced delays and numbers of tries, only to fit within the execution boundaries of dotnetfiddle)

Comment: Example showing `TimeoutStrategy.Optimistic`: https://dotnetfiddle.net/pnMdSQ   .  Many more examples in Polly's [Timeout unit tests](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/3143412a47bcc34f6274d75b3bd814b3e1a68f25/src/Polly.SharedSpecs/Timeout/TimeoutAsyncSpecs.cs) too.

Comment: A followup question if you have time: In my actual code I use a synchronous webservice call instead of the timeout. Since it's synchronous, i.e. not an awaitable task, I suppose a pessimistic timeout strategy is appropriate?

Comment: Check if it has a timeout anyway.  If not, pessimistic timeout allows caller to walk away after the timeout time.  But note that's exactly what it does.  The caller can walk away - but it doesn't magically cancel the timed-out call.  Nuances all discussed in [wiki](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Timeout#what-happens-to-the-timed-out-delegate) and the excellent [Stephen Toub article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/10/05/how-do-i-cancel-non-cancelable-async-operations/) I point to. HTH

Comment: You need to add `.Or<TimeoutRejectedException>()` to the handler if you want to retry the timed out attempt.

Comment: https://github.com/Polly-Contrib/Polly.Contrib.WaitAndRetry/

var retryWithBackoff = Policy
    .Handle<FooException>()
    .WaitAndRetryAsync(Backoff.ExponentialBackoff(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), retryCount: 5));
var timeout = Policy.Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(45));
var retryWithBackoffAndOverallTimeout = timeout.Wrap(retryWithBackoff);
When the combined time taken to make tries and wait between them exceeds 45 seconds, the TimeoutPolicy will be invoked and cause the current try and further retries to be abandoned.