# polly retry policy within given period of time

Tags: c#, polly, retry-logic

I have the following code:

```
var expirationPeriodMilliseconds = 1000;
return Policy
   .HandleResult<EnquiryResult>(message => message.Status == EnquiryStatus.SystemError)
   .RetryForeverAsync() // instead run until expirationPeriodMilliseconds
   .ExecuteAsync(async () => await ratingProvider.Enquire(request, cancellationToken));
```

Is there any solution for polly to use the retry option for a certain period of time?

Comment: Did you check the *other* `.RetryXXX` or `WaitAndRetry` methods ? Retry immediatelly or after a period? If the code retries immediatelly after a server fault the most likely outcome is to get the same fault.

Comment: Simply saying if EnquiryStatus.SystemError occurs I want to retry constantly for 1000 milliseconds.

Comment: You can use multiple policies, eg a Retry and Timeout. This was asked in [this issue from 2016](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/issues/184). You can wrap the `RetryForeverAsync` inside a `Timeout` with `myTimeout.Wrap(myRetry)`

Comment: More also in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43205503

Answer (score 0):

Even though it is a later answer it might be helpful for future readers

#### The policy definitions

```
var globalTimeoutPolicy = Policy
    .TimeoutAsync<EnquiryResult>(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(expirationPeriodMilliseconds));

var retryForeverPolicy = Policy
   .HandleResult<EnquiryResult>(message => message.Status == EnquiryStatus.SystemError)
   .RetryForeverAsync();

var combinedPolicy = Policy.WrapAsync(globalTimeoutPolicy, retryForeverPolicy);
```

- Here we have defined two policies

  - One for retrying the same action over and over again if it receives `SystemError`
  - Another to terminate the action after N milliseconds
- Finally we have chained/combined the policies into one

  - Because the `globalTimeoutPolicy` has been passed first to the `WrapAsync` that's why it is the outer policy so this timeout overarches all retry attempts
  - If we would pass the `globalTimeoutPolicy` as the second parameter of the `WrapAsync` then this timeout constraint would apply for each individual retry attempts

#### The usage of the chained policies

```
try
{
    var result = await combinedPolicy.ExecuteAsync(
         async (ct) => await ratingProvider.Enquire(request, ct), cancellationToken);
    Console.WriteLine($"Method has successfully completed with status: '{result.Status}'.");
}
catch(TimeoutRejectedException)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Method has failed after retrying for {expirationPeriodMilliseconds}ms.");
}
```

- Because your `ratingProvider.Enquire` method anticipates a `CancellationToken` that's why we can use [Optimistic timeout strategy](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Timeout#optimistic-timeout)

  - Polly will link together your `cancellationToken` with the TimeoutPolicy's `CancellationToken`
- If the timeout triggers and all previous retry attempts returned with `SystemError` then the `ExecuteAsync` will thrown an `TimeoutRejectedException`