# Retry multiple times when http request times out using polly c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dotnet-httpclient, connection-timeout, polly

My original intention was to retry multiple times when the request itself times out, such as when trying to communicate to another micro service which is down for a couple of seconds in the hope it is a temporary failure. If there is a simpler solution to do just that it would suffice.
I decided to manually set timeout per retry using a wrapping policy, hoping to achieve the same result.

I've seen a similar solution not using httpclientfactory here [Use a specific timeout connected to a retrypolicy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43201898/use-a-specific-timeout-connected-to-a-retrypolicy), but it doesn't work for me.

My code looks like this:

```
services.AddHttpClient("retryclient", client =>
{
    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100);
}).AddPolicyHandler((servs, request) =>
    Policy.HandleResult<HttpResponseMessage>(r =>
        {
            return r.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound; //(1)
        }).
.OrTransiesntHttpError().
WaitAndRetryAsync(5, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(retryAttempt),
    onRetry: (exception, timespan, retryAttempt, context) =>
        { // using servs to log // });
}).WrapAsync(Policy.TimeoutAsync(1)));
```

I have checked that the retry policy works when I try to access a 'not-found' adress without wrapping the timeout policy and it works fine. I've also tried to use line (1) with the status code `HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout` instead of not found for my case, but it doesn't work.

When I am using the wrapping and trying to access a service which is down it throws a `Polly.Timeout.TimeoutRejectedException` on the first try as I would have expected, but doesn't retry again. I couldn't figure a way to retry multiple time, either with a set timeout for each retry, or just when the request itself time outs not using a timeout policy.

Edit: After further reading  https://cm.engineering/transient-timeouts-and-the-retry-rabbit-hole-net-4-5-f406cebbf194 it seems my problem is inside the policy handling I don't have access to the cancellation token of the HttpClient. I assume I can fix it by overriding the sendAsync method as shown in link. Is there an elegant way to do same while creating the factory?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Polly documentation on HttpClientFactory](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Polly-and-HttpClientFactory) covers this in a section labelled [applying timeouts](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Polly-and-HttpClientFactory#use-case-applying-timeouts):

> You may want the retry policy to retry if any individual try timed out. To do this, make the retry policy handle the `TimeoutRejectedException` which Polly's timeout policy throws.

So:

```
services.AddHttpClient("retryclient", client =>
{
    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100);
}).AddPolicyHandler((servs, request) =>
    Policy.HandleResult<HttpResponseMessage>(r =>
        {
            return r.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound; //(1)
        }).
.OrTransientHttpError()
.Or<TimeoutRejectedException>() // ** ADDED **
.WaitAndRetryAsync(5, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(retryAttempt),
    onRetry: (exception, timespan, retryAttempt, context) =>
        { // using servs to log // });
})
.WrapAsync(Policy.TimeoutAsync(1)));
```

Polly passes the `CancellationToken` to the internal `.SendAsync()` call correctly; no changes should be needed concerning that.

Comment: Note that if the timeout of the client is too close to the policy timeout it might still fail and not retry again. I'm not sure why that happens, but I could just set the timeout of the client to a big enough number and it worked for me.

Comment: Agreed: that's covered by the documentation, which says: "`HttpClient.Timeout` will apply as an overall timeout to each entire call through `HttpClient`, including all tries and waits between retries."